# Extract information from string with dots as separator in R

Tags: r, string, stringi

I apologize for possible similar questions, but I just can't find the solution for my problem. So, I have a string with three parts, separated by `“.”`, for example:

```
a <- "XXX.YY.ZZZ"
```

(the length of strings differ, it could also be `a <- "XXXX.Y.ZZ"`, but the three parts are always separated by the two `“.”`.
I solved the problem for the first part:

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract(a, regex='[^.]*')
[1] "XXX"
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why not use `strsplit` instead?

Comment: Or `scan(what = "", text = a, sep = ".")`.

Comment: I think what you want is `stringi::stri_extract_all(a, regex='[^.]*')`?

Comment: Wau! So easy, it works! Thank you!

Comment: You were on the right track. Like @tyluRp said above, you just need to add the `_all` bit to the end of `str_extract`. The regex command I used was a bit different to extract only the characters:
`stringi::stri_extract_all(a, regex = "\\w+")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello you can use strsplit as follows

```
   strsplit(a,"\\.")[[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you @Begginer, your solution works as well.